# How to perform flash object testing in selenium webdriver with python?

Tags: python, flash, selenium, webdriver

After trying to find some help on the internet related to **flash testing** through selenium, all I find is **FlexUISelenium package available for Selenium RC**. I **DO NOT** find any such package available for **Selenium Webdriver**.

I am working with python and selenium webdriver and I do not see any packages available to automate flash applications. *Is there any such package available at all for webdriver?* If not, how do I start automating a flash application in webdriver?

Comment: Most likely the Flash itself must expose some kind of API which you can call through JavaScript, so that you can control it. Selenium issues JavaScript commands -> JavaScript issues Flash commands -> Flash component returns the testing results.

Comment: i havent used flexui and dont know if any such available for webdriver, but if it is available for RC then it can be called from webdriver by using webdriverbackedselenium. Not sure if flexui will work this way but you can test and let us know...

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa: Thanks for your answer. My problem is: How do I expose the ActionScripts so that I can use Javascript to handle them?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa: There is a site called Prezi.com which is a mixture of html and flash I guess. This site is for making presentations. I do not know how to share screenshots here so letting you know what I am trying to automate...

Comment: Random Google result http://ajaxian.com/archives/flash-javascript-integration-kit

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa: Sorry but this site didn't help me much. Can you help me in exposing the ActionScripts for the flash objects? Currently I am using FireFox's FlashFireBug. Is it of any help? However I am not able to see these actionscripts.Am I doing it right?

Comment: I think it would be easier to open a new question regarding this, because you cannot fit the answer to comments.

Answer (score 0):

Use flashselenium or sikuli for flash object testing.

Comment: I can use Flashselenium only with selenium RC and not with webdriver... Sikuli is an option which I am yet to try...

Comment: Selenium can't be able to automate applications in their own browsers So Selenium cannot test Flash(Silverlight too). Other options are Flexmonkey (there is Flexmonkium which is a Selenium FlexMonkey bridge) and Sikuli (Sikuli Script is built in Java with a Jython layer on top. All of the scripting is done in Python. But its hard to integrate sikuli with selenium but you can easily integrate selenium with sikuli by using jython)